# How to delete (discard) selected commits with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have the requirement where there are 10 commits in JGit. And among them I need to delete (discard) 5 commits. The rRemaining 5 commits are pushed.

I need a JGit code to find which commits are not pushed and want to discard those.

Currently I am trying rebasing using JGit And could find all the commits which are not pushed. But if they are in between of pushed commits then how to find them, discard them?

Comment: You can't easily do this, not without rewriting the history of the branch using something like an interactive rebase.  You would probably need a fair amount of code to do this.

Comment: found the commits which are not published using rebasing. But not getting how to discard them

Comment: Look into using interactive rebase.

Comment: Probably easiest is to use the `CherryPickCommand` to pick the desired commits onto a new branch whose start point is before the first commit to be discarded.